# how do I make cups use all cpu cores?

Tags: linux, cups, cpu-cores

I'm printing with cups from libreoffice, and the pc lasts a very long time preparing the printing, before actually sending it to the printer.

I'm seeing that it uses 100% of one core.

Is there a way to tell cups (or whatever else) to use more cores, so that less time is used preparing the printing?

I'm on linux, xubuntu 20.04

Comment: I've flagged the closure for the mods to review. I don't think this question should be closed, as the linked threads have nothing to do with this one. Also I've found a Github issue regarding your question, you can find it [here](https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/4511)

Comment: @mashuptwice the basic premise of the answers to the duplicates are the same regardless of the operating system. The application must be written in a way that makes use of more CPUs and you cannot "force" applications to do it. That github issue just says "we want to do this but no clue when" and that was 8 years ago, and no solid information stating that CUPS now actually *does* support multithreading.

Comment: @Mokubai From the creator of cups: "Slow LibreOffice printing isn't caused by a lack of threading support in cupsd" It seems that cupsd in fact supports multithreading. Note that this feature seemed to be added to cups in 2016.

Comment: @mashuptwice so the question needs to be rephrased away from the "how do I make CUPS use more cores?" Which *is what the dupes answer* to "how can I fix LibreOffice being slow to print to CUPS and causing high single core use?" Which would be a distinct question. As it stands it is the basic premise of this question, that OP wants to "tell cups to use more cores", that I have a problem with.

Comment: @Mokubai that indeed would be a more detailed description.